# Difference between cellular and simplicial homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Can someone tell me if there is any difference between cellular and simplicial homology?

It seems to me that when I calculate for example the homology groups of the torus it makes no conceptual difference whether I use cellular or simplicial homology. By that I mean: If I think of a zero cell as a vertex, a $1$-cell as an edge and a $2$-cell as an area then these are all simplices. As a consequence, if for example we want to argue that $C_2(T) = \mathbb Z$ then it is enough to either note that there is only one $2$-cell or, equivalently, that there is only one $2$-simplex.

Comment: Every simplicial decomposition of a space is a cellular decomposition, and then the simplicial  homology and the cellular homology are exactly the same (but not conversely; it is often the case that spaces have much more efficient cellular decomposition that triangulations)

Comment: Without going into details, any homology theory (in the sense of the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms) on CW-complexes is determined by $H_0$, mostly because of abstract nonsense. (We're not considering exotic theories here, only ones that satisfy the dimension axiom.) Of course, as mentioned below, even compact manifolds can't be triangulated in general.

Comment: There is no triangulation (as a $\Delta$-complex) of the torus with only one $2$-simplex!

Comment: In the situation Mariano describes, the simplicial and cellular homology are the same because the simplicial and cellular chain complexes are isomorphic.

Answer (score 6):

There are cases when simplicial homology can't be applied but cellular homology can, for example in the case of a compact manifold that can't be triangulated (which exist in dimensions greater than or equal to 4).

Comment: This is interesting, could you please provide an example of manifolds that cant be triangulated? I guess it´s not any manifold with dimension $\geq 4$, but are there any particular manifolds which can´t be triangulated?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova I have very little experience with this topic, but the manifolds that cannot be triangulated must have dimension at least 4. A reference that I'm looking at implies that maybe it's actually 5, but in any case here's a reference I found with google: https://people.math.osu.edu/davis.12/papers/dfl-agt.pdf

Answer (score 4):

All the cellular and simplicial homology groups of any (triangulable) space are isomorphic. For a proof see e.g. Hatcher.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in another answer here, simplicial homology can be regarded as a special case of cellular homology;  but the standard definition of the latter  and establishment of its  properties requires the main facts on singular homology.

For a short discussion of some history of algebraic topology, and some anomalies,  relevant to this question see this  [presentation](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/pdffiles/galway7.pdf).

The book partially titled [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/nonab-a-t.html) (EMS Tract Vol 15, 2011) takes a different approach to homology in that,  starting with a filtered space, $X_*$, for example the skeletal filtration of a CW-complex, we define directly and  **homotopically**,  using fundamental groupoids and relative homotopy groups , a "crossed complex" $\Pi X_*$,   which is a kind of  chain complex with operators, but partially, i.e. in dim $\leqslant 2$, nonabelian. Essential freeness results on this for the CW-filtration case are proved using a Higher Homotopy Seifert-van Kampen Theorem for $\Pi$; this theorem has an intuitive but roundabout  proof, using cubical groupoid methods to give "algebraic inverses to subdivision".

This approach replaces by actual compositions,  i.e. higher dimensional analogues of compositions of paths,  the "formal sums" standard in the usual approach. It  allows for  results which are nonabelian in dimension $\leqslant 2$, and are on modules in  dimensions $> 1$, the latter without using covering spaces.

Part of the inspiration for this approach comes from J.H.C. Whitehead's 1949 paper "Combinatorial Homotopy II".